# How to deal with background image orientation in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background-image, screen-orientation

I'm using setting the background image using methodology below. When I rotate my device the background repeats, which make sense because it is not an image. How do I deal with orientation change if this is the way I'm setting my background image?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me awhile to understand this concept. I didn't want to create the same image portrait and landscape. The key here is that `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` rotates from the original state of your UIImageView or any UIView for that matter. This assumes your background image has orientation to it. E.g. You want your UIImageView to stay put, while other objects behaves to normal orientation change event.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {  
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
    }
    else {
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set the UIImageView to current UIView frame
    backgroundImage.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Your background gets created or overwritten every time you change the orientation right. By default `backgroundColor` is `nil`. You can check for this, if it is nil then you go ahead and set the values.
Its like

```
if ( self.view.backgroundColor == nil){
    //set the new values here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take 2 images both for horizontal and vertical and instead of allocating you can use `[...: colorWithPatternImage:...];` and set it when orientation is changed to the background of the view.

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: I want to avoid making the same image landscape. Is using UIImageView the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a way to keep the background image stationary and just rotate the rest of my UIs?

Comment: yeah try using imageview. It will work. but u need to set the frame as per view.. hope u got what i wanna say..

Comment: I request a better answer for this. I don't want to rotate the background image, just the other views on top of it, when device is tilted...

Comment: Okay I just researched a nice solution. What do you mean by "set the frame as per view"? Can you elaborate using code?

Comment: Hello Jonny. I tried to rotate individually. It rotates fine, but I'll need to write all the positioning function. Unless you have a simpler way, it is a lot more trouble than rotating the background image itself.

Comment: it means incase of universal app... imageview.frame=self.view.frame thats it

Comment: Thanks I just modified the code to make sure my current UIView.frame is the same as my background UIImageView.frame.