# how to make the background image rotate?

Tags: iphone

When I rotate my app the background image will not rotate and
I wish that my background image will rotate.
The content do changes the orientation but the background image stays and will not rotate.

Any ideas on a go around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to apply a graphics "transform" to modify your image when the device is rotated.  See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592192/how-to-deal-with-background-image-orientation-in-uiview)... In your image controller, add the following code (where backgroundImage is a property containing your image.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {  
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
    }
    else {
        backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is the way to stop the rotation i will make the changes to make it rotate